# Python Slicing text file into arrays based on field value

Tags: python, arrays, timestamp

I am new to Python and I want to read a text file that has three fields; `X`, `Y` and `Time`. I want to form arrays from the x and y fields as long as the time field is still the constant. For example:

```
X    Y     Time
1    2     100
3    4     100
5    6     100
7    8     200
9    10    200
```

therefore, for `time = 100`, I build `x_array = [1,3,5]` and `y_array = [2,4,6]` as input to other processes and then go back to update them when time change to `200`.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', delim_whitespace=True)

>>> df.groupby('Time')['X'].apply(list).to_dict()
{100: [1, 3, 5], 200: [7, 9]}

>>> df.groupby('Time')['Y'].apply(list).to_dict()
{100: [2, 4, 6], 200: [8, 10]}
```

### Explanation

This reads you file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
```

into such a dataframe:

[image]

Now, you group by `Time` and convert the entries in `X` into lists:

```
df.groupby('Time')['X'].apply(list)
```

This gives you this pandas series:

```
Time
100    [1, 3, 5]
200       [7, 9]
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Finally, use `to_dict()` to convert it to a dictionary:

```
>>> df.groupby('Time')['X'].apply(list).to_dict()
{100: [1, 3, 5], 200: [7, 9]}
```

### Alternative Solution:

This gives you a different arrangement of the result:

```
>>> df.groupby('Time').apply(lambda x: {'X': list(x['X']), 'Y': list(x['Y'])}).to_dict()
{100: {'X': [1, 3, 5], 'Y': [2, 4, 6]}, 200: {'X': [7, 9], 'Y': [8, 10]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want a dictionary of keys based on time, something along the lines:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = {}
    next(f)    # Skip header
    for line in f:
        x, y, time = map(int, line.strip().split())
        data.setdefault(time, {})
        data[time].setdefault('X', []).append(x)
        data[time].setdefault('Y', []).append(y)
data
# {100: {'X': [1, 3, 5], 'Y': [2, 4, 6]}, 200: {'X': [7, 9], 'Y': [8, 10]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task that [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) should cover nicely with the `csv` module's `DictReader`. This creates a very readable piece of code for parsing:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# these two will hold xs and ys by time point
xs = defaultdict(list)
ys = defaultdict(list)

with open("yourfile.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
         # get time point for row
        t = row['Time']
        # add x point
        xs[t].append(row['X'])
        # add y point
        ys[t].append(row['Y'])

print xs
print ys
```

Output:

> defaultdict(, {'200': ['7', '9'], '100': ['1', '3', '5']})
>
> defaultdict(, {'200': ['8', '10'], '100': ['2', '4', '6']})